# Kitchen.sh Seems to not loading pentaho-big-data-plugin?

Tags: kettle

I try to execute my kjb file which simply copy a local file to hdfs using kitchen.sh. But it seems not loading big-data-plugin.

Because when I try to execute the same kjb file using Spoon.sh, it works fine.

So Any ideas?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job>
  <name>test</name>
  <description/>
  <extended_description/>
  <job_version/>
  <directory>&#x2f;</directory>
  <created_user>-</created_user>
  <created_date>2017&#x2f;01&#x2f;07 18&#x3a;24&#x3a;12.549</created_date>
  <modified_user>-</modified_user>
  <modified_date>2017&#x2f;01&#x2f;07 18&#x3a;24&#x3a;12.549</modified_date>
    <parameters>
    </parameters>
    <slaveservers>
    </slaveservers>
      <job-log-table>
        <connection/>
        <schema/>
        <table/>
        <size_limit_lines/>
        <interval/>
        <timeout_days/>
        <field>
          <id>ID_JOB</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ID_JOB</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>CHANNEL_ID</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>CHANNEL_ID</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>JOBNAME</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>JOBNAME</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>STATUS</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>STATUS</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_READ</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_READ</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_WRITTEN</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_WRITTEN</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_UPDATED</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_UPDATED</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_INPUT</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_INPUT</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_OUTPUT</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_OUTPUT</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_REJECTED</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_REJECTED</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>ERRORS</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ERRORS</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>STARTDATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>STARTDATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>ENDDATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ENDDATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOGDATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LOGDATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>DEPDATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>DEPDATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>REPLAYDATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>REPLAYDATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOG_FIELD</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LOG_FIELD</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>EXECUTING_SERVER</id>
          <enabled>N</enabled>
          <name>EXECUTING_SERVER</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>EXECUTING_USER</id>
          <enabled>N</enabled>
          <name>EXECUTING_USER</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>START_JOB_ENTRY</id>
          <enabled>N</enabled>
          <name>START_JOB_ENTRY</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>CLIENT</id>
          <enabled>N</enabled>
          <name>CLIENT</name>
        </field>
      </job-log-table>
      <jobentry-log-table>
        <connection/>
        <schema/>
        <table/>
        <timeout_days/>
        <field>
          <id>ID_BATCH</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ID_BATCH</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>CHANNEL_ID</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>CHANNEL_ID</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOG_DATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LOG_DATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>JOBNAME</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>TRANSNAME</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>JOBENTRYNAME</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>STEPNAME</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_READ</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_READ</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_WRITTEN</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_WRITTEN</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_UPDATED</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_UPDATED</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_INPUT</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_INPUT</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_OUTPUT</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_OUTPUT</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LINES_REJECTED</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LINES_REJECTED</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>ERRORS</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ERRORS</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>RESULT</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>RESULT</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>NR_RESULT_ROWS</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>NR_RESULT_ROWS</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>NR_RESULT_FILES</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>NR_RESULT_FILES</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOG_FIELD</id>
          <enabled>N</enabled>
          <name>LOG_FIELD</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>COPY_NR</id>
          <enabled>N</enabled>
          <name>COPY_NR</name>
        </field>
      </jobentry-log-table>
      <channel-log-table>
        <connection/>
        <schema/>
        <table/>
        <timeout_days/>
        <field>
          <id>ID_BATCH</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ID_BATCH</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>CHANNEL_ID</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>CHANNEL_ID</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOG_DATE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LOG_DATE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>LOGGING_OBJECT_TYPE</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>LOGGING_OBJECT_TYPE</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>OBJECT_NAME</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>OBJECT_NAME</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>OBJECT_COPY</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>OBJECT_COPY</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>REPOSITORY_DIRECTORY</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>REPOSITORY_DIRECTORY</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>FILENAME</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>FILENAME</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>OBJECT_ID</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>OBJECT_ID</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>OBJECT_REVISION</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>OBJECT_REVISION</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>PARENT_CHANNEL_ID</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>PARENT_CHANNEL_ID</name>
        </field>
        <field>
          <id>ROOT_CHANNEL_ID</id>
          <enabled>Y</enabled>
          <name>ROOT_CHANNEL_ID</name>
        </field>
      </channel-log-table>
   <pass_batchid>N</pass_batchid>
   <shared_objects_file/>
  <entries>
    <entry>
      <name>START</name>
      <description/>
      <type>SPECIAL</type>
      <start>Y</start>
      <dummy>N</dummy>
      <repeat>N</repeat>
      <schedulerType>0</schedulerType>
      <intervalSeconds>0</intervalSeconds>
      <intervalMinutes>60</intervalMinutes>
      <hour>12</hour>
      <minutes>0</minutes>
      <weekDay>1</weekDay>
      <DayOfMonth>1</DayOfMonth>
      <parallel>N</parallel>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      <nr>0</nr>
      <xloc>128</xloc>
      <yloc>192</yloc>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <name>Success</name>
      <description/>
      <type>SUCCESS</type>
      <parallel>N</parallel>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      <nr>0</nr>
      <xloc>432</xloc>
      <yloc>160</yloc>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <name>Hadoop Copy Files</name>
      <description/>
      <type>HadoopCopyFilesPlugin</type>
      <copy_empty_folders>Y</copy_empty_folders>
      <arg_from_previous>N</arg_from_previous>
      <overwrite_files>N</overwrite_files>
      <include_subfolders>N</include_subfolders>
      <remove_source_files>N</remove_source_files>
      <add_result_filesname>N</add_result_filesname>
      <destination_is_a_file>N</destination_is_a_file>
      <create_destination_folder>N</create_destination_folder>
      <fields>
        <field>
          <source_filefolder>&#x2f;opt&#x2f;tmp.txt</source_filefolder>
          <source_configuration_name>LOCAL-SOURCE-FILE-0</source_configuration_name>
          <destination_filefolder>hdfs&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;sn-node1&#x3a;8020&#x2f;tmp</destination_filefolder>
          <destination_configuration_name>test</destination_configuration_name>
          <wildcard/>
        </field>
      </fields>
      <parallel>N</parallel>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      <nr>0</nr>
      <xloc>272</xloc>
      <yloc>176</yloc>
    </entry>
  </entries>
  <hops>
    <hop>
      <from>START</from>
      <to>Hadoop Copy Files</to>
      <from_nr>0</from_nr>
      <to_nr>0</to_nr>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <evaluation>Y</evaluation>
      <unconditional>Y</unconditional>
    </hop>
    <hop>
      <from>Hadoop Copy Files</from>
      <to>Success</to>
      <from_nr>0</from_nr>
      <to_nr>0</to_nr>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <evaluation>Y</evaluation>
      <unconditional>N</unconditional>
    </hop>
  </hops>
  <notepads>
  </notepads>
</job>
```

Comment: I think plugin suppose to be defined on jvm start as parameter -DKETTLE_PLUGIN_CLASSES=

Comment: Since kitchen.sh just a wrapper of spoon.sh and variable responsible for it $KETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES

Comment: But How to set this variable, what is the value like? I checked the script's code and found the variable, But had no sight of setting a value to it....

Comment: It is in here https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle/blob/master/project.launch

Comment: Look into key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.VM_ARGUMENTS"